# Mercurial reporting - Revision and file change report available?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm looking for a way to view all of a repository's branches and each file that has changed in that branch. I'm not interested in the file level changes as this report is for simple auditing.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hg log -b <branchname> --template "{files} "
```

Plus some post-processing, because output will be like this

lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_assigncategories/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_entryproperties/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_freetag/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_gravatar/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_relatedlinks/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_nl2br/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php plugins/serendipity_event_freetag/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php

Comment: Is there a way to have it iterate through all branches?

Comment: omit -b, will be "all branches"

Comment: In the files collection, they are space delimeted. How can I add a '/n' so each file is on a new line? Also, is there a way to show if the file was deleted, modified or just added? I see file_adds and file_dels but not modified.

Comment: \n can be obtained with piping output to sed (first dirty idea), which will replace spaces with newlines. Yes, you can separate files by operation type, just use another keywords `   file_adds   List of strings. Files added by this changeset.
   file_copies
               List of strings. Files copied in this changeset with their
               sources.
   file_dels   List of strings. Files removed by this changeset.
   file_mods   List of strings. Files modified by this changeset.`

Comment: example `>hg log -r 0:2 --template
 "{rev\n}\nA - {file_adds}\nD - {file_dels}\nM - {file_mods}\n\n"`

Comment: result `0
A - .hgignore README TODO __init__.py fetch_command.py hg_delta_editor.py push_cmd.py svncommand.py svnwrap/__init__.py svnwrap/svn_ctypes_wrapper.py svnwrap/svn_swig_wrapper.py test_fetch_command.py test_svnwrap.py util.py utility_commands.py
D - 
M - 

1
A - 
D - TODO
M - 

2
A - 
D - 
M - README` Sorry, newlines eaten by comment-engine

Comment: Good stuff but let me rephrase. If i run this 'hg log -r 0:2 --template "{files}\n", i get this "File1 File2 File3" when I want "File1 (carriagereturn)File2 (carriagereturn)File3 (carriagereturn)"

Comment: As I wrote "\n can be obtained with piping output to sed, which will replace spaces with newlines." If you haven't sed on windows side - convert file non-interactively with GrepWin

Answer (score 0):

Use `hg status` to get information about files that have changed between revisions. See the [revset language](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) for how to select the revisions.

If you want to see file changes between the first and last changesets on branch `B`:

```
$ hg status --rev "min(branch(B)):max(branch(B))"
```

You can even make an alias for this:

```
[alias]
audit = status --rev "min(branch($1)):max(branch($1))"
```

and then use `hg audit B` to get the same result.